# Script aborts after 300 seconds, although max_execution_time = 2400 is defined in php.ini

Tags: php, xampp, php-ini, max-execution-timeout

I have a local XAMPP with PHP 8 installed.

1. ```php
   echo ini_get('max_execution_time');
   ```

   also results the

   > 2400

   from `php.ini`.
2. ```php
   echo "Max execution time: ".ini_get("max_execution_time")."<br />";
   echo "Max input time: ".ini_get("max_input_time")."<br />";`
   ```

   > Max execution time: 2400
   > Max input time: 60
3. ```php
   ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1');
   ```

   no change:

   > Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs..\inc\datenbank.php on line xx

Comment: These directives might be case sensitive. I cannot find this in the manual, but why not try `ini_set('max_execution_time', ....);` instead of `ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', ....);`? And please, use a number instead of a string value.

Comment: Which php.ini ?  apache, cli , fpm ? also, how are you testing ?

Comment: My script starts (now) with the following code: `<?php

echo "Max execution time: ".ini_get("max_execution_time")."<br>";
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
echo "Max execution time: ".ini_get("max_execution_time")."<br>";
echo "Max input time: ".ini_get("max_input_time")."<br><br>";
`

Comment: @YvesLeBorg apache php.ini

Comment: @ThomasKujawa so, are you testing from  from browser , from browser whilst php is run through php-fpm ?   just make sure you are editing the .ini that corresponds to your test circumstances.